# forkJoin not waiting for multiple Http requests to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

So I have three http requests that I am passing to forkJoin:

```
apiRequest1 = this.http.getApi1('...');
// The same format is for the remaining api requests.

forkJoin(apiRequest1, apiRequest2, apiRequest3)
    .subscribe(([results1, results2, results3]) => { rest of code }
```

the data in results3 keeps coming back as an empty array. If I run the HttpRequest by itself and subscribe to it, the data comes back just fine. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: forkJoin expects the passed observables to *complete* -- if they are not completed -- no go.

Comment: can you post more from the api requests themselves? This could possibly have to do with the `this` scope in the method. It's not a problem with `forkJoin` itself.

Comment: @Rafael I know that. That's why I am wanting to use forkJoin in the instance. I want all three http calls to complete before processing any further code below the subscribe parenthesis. The weird thing is when I run the third api call by itself instead of within forkJoin, it completes just fine.One thing to note is all three api calls within forkJoin do complete (I see it in the console), its just for some reason forkJoin itself isn't waiting for the last one to complete before processing the code in the subscription method call.

Comment: It must be completing erroneously, but how can we know without seeing the code for it!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try the below:

```
forkJoin(
  apiRequest1, apiRequest2, apiRequest3
).subscribe(
    response =>{
      //response[0] is data returned by API apiRequest1
      //response[1] is data returned by API apiRequest2
      //response[2] is data returned by API apiRequest3
    }
    error => console.log("Error: ", error),
    () =>{
      //All the API calls are completed here. Put your code here
      //codes should be executed after the completion of all API calls
    }
)
```